# Where can I purchase tickets for the 2018 World Cup?

Tags: football, world-cup, fifa

Where can I purchase tickets for the 2018 World Cup?

- If I cannot find any tickets online to buy, can I get tickets from the stadium two or three days before the match?
- Can I apply for a "wheelchair user" FIFA ticket even if I am not a disabled person? They opened the W ticket section online with tickets selling for $105.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. As it stands right now: **No**. Tickets are sold on the respective [Website](http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/organisation/ticketing/index.html) only and possibly in so-called *Ticket Venue Centres* sometime during the final sales phase if there are still enough tickets for sale for a certain game (There is no news about the exact time and location yet, but for the Confed Cup there were three: St. Petersburg, Sochi and Moscow). If there are any tickets left from the previous stage (e.g. ordered but not paid for in time) they will be sold in the next stages. Even the last minute sales will be held online. If there are still tickets available after that the FIFA will publish information in time about how to order them (Online or as of then maybe even in Ticket Venue Centres).

[Ticket Sales Regulations:](http://resources.fifa.com/mm/document/tournament/ticketing/02/90/39/71/2018fwc-en-ticketsalesregulationsforgeneralpublic(international)_neutral.pdf)

> 5.1 Tickets will be made available in different sales phases. FIFA has the right to determine the number of Tickets made available for sale
>   to the  general public and other customer groups in each of the sales
>   phases.  **The sales phases are described in the Ticket Application Form**
>   and further Ticket sales materials which FIFA may publish and update
>   from time to time.

2. **No**. Definitely not. Special Access Tickets are that for a reason and they want [proof](http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/organisation/ticketing/special-access-tickets.html):

> Please note that customers who apply for Special Access Tickets are
>   required to **provide proof of eligibility documents** as part of the
>   Ticket Application process. If not already provided and approved
>   online, such proof of eligibility documents must be provided upon
>   Ticket collection (if applicable) or when purchasing Tickets over the
>   counter as well as, upon request, at the entrance to the Stadium.

Comment: I need to buy a ticket for germany and mexico but it is closed. The tickets are sold or it may be opened in the next phase ?

Comment: @droidnation it is possible that it will be reopened again during the next phase. It always happens that some unsold or unallocated tickets will be made available again... but usually Germany's games are sold out early, so you need some luck. Just don't fall for viagogo and the likes.. they're known for screwing people over (and they're [banned](http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/news/y=2018/m=1/news=fifa-obtains-preliminary-injunction-against-viagogo-2926697.html)).

Comment: What is this: `In the Last Minute Sales Phase from 18th April 2018 up until the final Match day of the Competition, the remaining Tickets will be available to all customers online and, from a date to be defined up until the final Match day of the competition, remaining Tickets will also be available Over the Counter at the designated FIFA Venue Ticketing Centres. During the Last Minute Sales Phase, Ticket purchases are processed as a real-time transaction to the extent inventory remains available`

Comment: These are special locations where you can buy tickets directly as of 18th April. The FIFA has placed a lot of locations where you can collect your purchased tickets and three of them actually sell them too. I'll append them to my answer

Comment: @droidnation added to my answer.. These are usually for the less frequented games, though. They can't sell tickets for already sold out games :)

Comment: Even round 2 are sold ?

Comment: @droidnation we don't know that yet. FIFA will announce how they sell them.